# Ponteiros na faculdade

Tags: c, ubuntu, ponteiro

Estou estudando ponteiros e esse é um código usado como exemplo que esta no material dado pela faculdade. Fui replicar esse código na minha maquina e a saída é diferente da apresentada no material.
Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=5, y=7, teste=21, aux=17;
    int *px, *py;

    px = &y;
    py = &x;

    printf("py - px = %d\n",py-px);
    printf("px = %u, *px=%d, &px = %d\n",px, *px, &px);
    printf("py = %u, *py=%d, &py = %d\n",py, *py, &py);
    px++;
    printf("px = %u, px=%d, &px = %d\n",px, *px, &px);

    py = px+3;
    printf("py = %u, *py=%d, &py = %d\n",py, *py, &py);
    printf("py - px = %d\n",py - px);

    return 0;
}
```

Logo abaixo esta a saída do programa na minha maquina:

```
py - px = -1<br>
px = 3782591132, *px=7, &px = -512376152
py = 3782591128, *py=5, &py = -512376144
px = 3782591136, *px=21, &px = -512376152
py = 3782591148, *py=32767, &py = -512376144
py - px = 3
```

Também utilizo uma [IDE Online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_ide.php) de C para estudar e a saída do programa é a mesma que esta no material da faculdade.

Saída no IDE Online:

```
py - px = 1                                                                                                                                                               
px = 2271354488, *px=7, &px = -2023612824                                                                                                                                 
py = 2271354492, *py=5, &py = -2023612832                                                                                                                                 
px = 2271354492, *px=5, &px = -2023612824                                                                                                                                  
py = 2271354504, *py=593585370, &py = -2023612832                                                                                                                         
py - px = 3
```

De acordo com o material, o ponteiro *px* aponta para a variável *x* e após o incremento ela deveria apontar para a variável y.

No entanto na minha máquina, esta apontando para a variável *teste*. E na linha de subtração entre os ponteiros *px* e *py* o resulta seria 1 e não -1.

Não sei o que pode estar de errado.

Estou usando Ubuntu 16.4.5 com gcc 5.4 e gcc 7.1 ambos com mesma saída.
E a IDE Online é RED HAT 7.1.1-3 com gcc 7.1.1.

Comment: Você não tem garantia que `x` e `y` estão consecutivos. O compilador é livre para por a ordem desejada

Answer (score 1):

No caso apresentado o programa realmente apresentará saídas diferentes em cada máquina, e às vezes a cada execução, pois o valor armazenado em um ponteiro é um endereço de memória. O problema é que por não ser um array, pode ser que x e y não sejam posições contíguas na memória então incrementar x não necessariamente vai parar em y. (Lembrando que na aritmética de ponteiros a soma e a subtração levam para frente a para trás nas posições de memória)

Para exemplificar o que estou dizendo veja a alteração que fiz no seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int array[] = {5, 7, 21, 17, 50};
    int *px, *py;

    px = array;
    py = px+1;

    printf("py - px = %d\n", py - px);
    printf("px = %u, *px=%d, &px = %d\n",px, *px, &px);
    printf("py = %u, *py=%d, &py = %d\n",py, *py, &py);
    px++;
    printf("px = %u, px=%d, &px = %d\n",px, *px, &px);

    py = px+3;
    printf("py = %u, *py=%d, &py = %d\n",py, *py, &py);
    printf("py - px = %d\n",py - px);

    return 0;
}
```

*Obs.: Tive que colocar mais uma posição no array pois py+3 acessava uma variável fora do array.*

A saída apresentada é a seguinte:

```
py - px = 1 // 1 espaço de diferença
px = 2865090736, *px=5, &px = -1429876568
py = 2865090740, *py=7, &py = -1429876576
px = 2865090740, px=7, &px = -1429876568
py = 2865090752, *py=50, &py = -1429876576
py - px = 3
```

Perceba agora as posições na memória:

```
 x ->  0. 2865090736 // 2865090736 + 4*0
 y ->  1. 2865090740 // 2865090736 + 4*1
       2. 2865090744 // 2865090736 + 4*2
       3. 2865090748 // 2865090736 + 4*3
y+3->  4. 2865090752 // 2865090736 + 4*4
```

4 bytes é o espaço que um int ocupa.